# Cycles rendering on 3x1080ti ----2x1080 with slow CPU and low RAM

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu, hardware

I'm trying to use my mining rig like render farm.
All carts are connected by raisers PCI-E x1 not PCI-E x16 ports.

1. MB:  ASUS Z97-E/C/SI
2. CPU: Celeron G1840
3. Ram: 2GB
4. GPU: 3x1080TI 3x1080

I use blender 2.79 for render test and when I push render button screen is switch off.
I test it on Linux and on Windows, but result is the same. 
how you think what is the minimal upgrade I have to do for starting render on this rig.
Thanks for your coments and excuse for my English.

Comment: I forgot about power supply 1600W

Comment: It is not very clear to me what you are asking. Could you please explain the problem more clearly? Are you asking whether it is possible to render with multiple GPUs? What do GPUs have to do with a rig?

Comment: problem: my pc with 6 gpu cannot start rendering image in blender cycles.Question: how can i upgrade my pc with 6 gpu for starting rendering in blender? P.S. rig=PC

Comment: I suspect RAM is the bottleneck here. Try a 16GB stick?